# WSO2 EI HOW TO INVALIDATE CACHE MEDIATOR INSIDE A SERVICE PROXY

Tags: caching, jmx, invalidation, wso2-enterprise-integrator, mediator

I was trying to invalidate the cache mediator using an header mediator inside my sequence but unfortunately it doesn't work:

```
<header name="Cache-Control" scope="transport" value="no-cache"/>
<cache collector="false" timeout="2592000">
    <protocol type="HTTP">
        <methods>*</methods>
        <headersToExcludeInHash/>
        <responseCodes>.*</responseCodes>
        <enableCacheControl>true</enableCacheControl>
        <includeAgeHeader>true</includeAgeHeader>
        <hashGenerator>org.wso2.carbon.mediator.cache.digest.HttpRequestHashGenerator</hashGenerator>
    </protocol>
</cache>
```

Then i was trying to implement a MBean so i can clear the cache and i was wondering how to do from a proxy service the entire wheel. Can anyone post an example how to invalidate all cached response remotely by using any JMX monitoring tool by MBeans? Thanks

Comment: Did you try out this documentation? https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Cache+Mediator#CacheMediator-Invalidatingcachedresponsesremotely

Comment: Onestly i didn't understand how to use the method invalideTheWholeCache....